# Are afterimages centrally regulated?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, vision, eyes

As I understand, negative afterimages might be induced by retinal cone bleaching or neuronal adaptation. I have heard that some experiments have suggested that afterimages can be centrally regulated. Is this true, and if so, what is the evidence?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about a problem in biology, but a request for literature about a subject. This would have been obvious if you had finished the [Tour], as one would expect of new users to this site.

Comment: Welcome to SE biology.  Generic queries and requests for literature reviews aren't in scope for the forum. If you have a specific question you could edit this or post a new question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @David asking for help with literature is neither listed on the "do" list nor on the "do not" list. I do not know if it was my question that necessitated your tone or something else.

Comment: @Michael_A thank you! I updated my question, hopefully, brought it into the scope of the forum.

Comment: @aninstance The scope is much better, but we expect questions to be supported with some prior research. So, when you say you understand something to be true, it's best to provide a citation/reference where you found that information. When you write "I have heard that", it's best to specify *where* you've heard and what specifically was said. Probably also worth clarifying what you mean by "centrally", as the meaning of "central" depends on your point of reference.